# How to load python scripts to OBS Studio

Tags: python, obs

How do I load my python scripts into OBS Studio? I used the Tools/Script and click the '+' and tried to navigate to my python script but it is greyed out. Only Lua scripts are allowed.

Comment: Have you read and followed the documentation? https://obsproject.com/docs/scripting.html - this isn't really a coding question, so it's not really the right place for it.

Comment: Yes. Nothing in the document mentioned how to load python scripts or why .py files are excluded.

Comment: From that page: "To use Python on windows, you must download and install Python 3.6.x “x86-64” for OBS 64bit (64bit is the default), or Python 3.6.x “x86” if using OBS 32bit. Then, in the scripting dialog, you must set the path to the Python 3.6.x install in the “Python Settings” tab." - so you've done that, and yet you don't have the option to add Python scripts?

Comment: I'm on Mac and using OBS 26.0.2. There's no "Python Settings" tab when I open the script dialog.